# Limit inrush current after emergency stop relay

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, current-limiting, pmos, inrush-current

I have a power board with an emergency stop (using a mechanical relay). The input voltage is 24V and on the power board I have multiple DCDC converters, some before the emergency stop and some after. See figure below.

[image]

When I disengage the emergency stop, there is a sag in my input voltage causing some of the DCDC converters on the input side of the relay to reset. I believe this is because I am switching in a large capacitive load (the DCDC converters). You can see the scope trace below (Yellow: 24V input, Blue: 24V after relay):

[image]

To alleviate this issue I have tried

1. A thermistor which alleviated the issue but my converters after the relay will draw a total of 15A on the 24V line which is quite large for a thermistor, also the wait time after pressing the emergency stop is something I would like to avoid.
2. A [PMOS circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsAoAc1sJpGwRRbZriinoA3bu04jMXKlV4gUbKVGgJ6AJ3aQ2aPOs0ZJyOPQBmshIVl7T5re2y1FNegHcds-O0LabkZ65sS3bR81FDMLLlDzbGxzKmIfZkjaPiSaGiCBF14qG2zwQilfdMDaLxkfAGN82RkwKLR%20GDgwCEK1PByZDvYGqjAfLO1sBuLsPHkmUvZxqbzClzqa6TL5qbkqbvXMkG7h5Z7V0YbFve2wYgj3MDSSgfALkq3vehjtRa2AWmKtwoATZL6BREdRyIF%20AFMjABDACuABsAC5FVj5aQo57YDA5MLRaw4zzgRovLHgG65LxXIkAD1oLVk2AgNAQmmwPHASAAoh8AM4IgD2AAdkbouDR0e4fDSaBhNMQ7AgxrJiOY2GAkHIAGoAHW5AEkAHYCmFIkw2MaaHEzYbgJQ2vD0ABKqOmqqBuMayRqHpgym5AJKYs0EsJ0Lh3PBviSAVwIu2ZpmIJdZweASjlkq90ubxT6cU8EgpELReLpDzkFasHLRRS7letxeBJj4Vs1jwGR8fLcIBR0gLxDLcAwhBQcuITIZoQHBaHZknoIaDE7MW78mSpaa5ZQaCxE6QG7Vw6QEC4y4YQA) outlined below however this made no difference on the voltage sag and in fact I ended up blowing up the bottom resistor on the voltage divider. It may be better to move the emergency stop to control the N-channel MOSFET gate which I will now try.

[image]

I think the P-channel will work for the high current I need to work with but I am not sure what I have done wrong or if there is a different solution.

Appreciate any hints. If there are details missing in my description, my apology in advance.

Comment: You could use a hotswap controller like this one from TI: https://www.ti.com/product/LM5066I

Comment: Depending on whether or not the converters need to come on simultaneously, you could add a delay so that they power up in sequence, spreading out the inrush current over three smaller spikes.  You could also try adding some capacitance on the supply side of the relay, but I'd be careful about how much current you allow to go through the relay contacts.

Comment: Or add a large electrolytic capacitor or cap + supercapacitor to the supply line. Supercaps have higher impedance than an electrolytic of the same value, so might not provide peak currents alone.

Comment: Get the 12 V supply to switch on a 12 V relay which switches on the 5 V supply which energises a 5 V relay which powers up the 3.3 V supply. Click. Click. All on!

Comment: Usually the E-STOP cuts off the power to the actuators. Now DC/DC converter is not an actuator, moreover it has a large capacitance, so that continues to work even when E-STOP is activated, therefore it doesn't meet the basic rule of emergency stop. You have to add relays/switches only to the actuators, not on control logic.

Comment: Check your gate voltages, I do not know of many MOSFETs that will survive long with a 24V VGS voltage.